# Entityframework Core Group Join Third Parameter does not populates the data member

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have been trying to do a group join, I have searched a lot but is not able to make my way towards the solution. Although I am following the same syntax as mentioned in the documentation and is available on the internet. But yet the third parameter for a GroupJoin is not showing me the data members of that particular class. 
[image]

Note: All the data members within the _context.Board_Attachments are public.

Comment: Definitely Intellisense bug. Same happens with `Join`. Have to type the valid property manually.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment. I will take care of it.